# Laravel echo and relationships wrong data in event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

my problem is that i can't seem to return a newly created record with it's relationships to a event.

i have this store method.

```
public function store(Request $request){
$post = new Post($request->all());
$post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$post->save();

$createdPost = Post::with('owner')->findOrFail($post->id);
event(new PostCreatedEvent($createdPost));
return $createdTicket;
}
```

now i expect this to return data like

```
{
"post": {
"id": 10,
"title": '"hello",
"body": "world",
"user_id": 1,
"created_at": date,
"updated_at": date,
"owner": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name",
        "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

And i do get this from the return in the store method.
But in the event that gets sent to pusher i get this

```
{
    "post": {
        "id": 10,
        "title": '"hello",
        "body": "world",
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": date,
        "updated_at": date,
    }
}
```

My question is why does the event strip out the owner data from before sending it to pusher and how can i fix it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Provide some more information.

Comment: Edited the op with a direct question in the end.

Comment: Can you show your `PostCreatedEvent` class?

Comment: class PostCreatedEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
        public $post;
        public function __construct($post)
        {
            $this->post = $post;
            $this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
        }
        public function broadcastOn()
        {
            return new PrivateChannel('post.created');
        }
    }

Comment: @AmitGupta seems like formatting diden't work in the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is something happening with the data when it gets to the event class. After not being able to fix it i tried some random solutions.

```
$createdPost = Post::with('owner')->findOrFail($post->id)->toJson();
```

This did the trick. I now need to json parse it on the frontend but all the data is coming through.